# error installing python wrapper for openkinect

Tags: python, openkinect

I tried to install python wrappers for OpenKinect on Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't due this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev 
python2.7-dev : Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Python wrapper requires these dependencies:

1. Cython
2. python-dev (error above)
3. python-numpy

I have reviewed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59563/how-to-install-a-different-version-of-python-dev), but it doesn't work for me

how can I install python-dev?

Comment: did you try to install libexpat1-dev and libssl-dev separately already?

Answer (score 0):

Mark all checkboxes on Updates section and reload sources.

[image]